# Dart: why primitive type behaves like a reference type?

Tags: dart

Look at this code:

```java
void main() {
    int i = 10;
    var someFunc = () {
        int ni = i;
        print(ni)
    };
    i = 20;
    someFunc(); // 20
}
```

This code will print 20, but why? Why primitive type in this case behaves like a reference type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
int ni = i;
```

won't execute until you call `someFunc()`, so the only value that the `int ni` will hold is the last one you have assigned to `int i` before calling `someFunc()`

In other words, `int ni` is not a pointer (a reference type) to `i`, it just does not update his value (the value of `ni`) until you call `someFunc()`

Comment: This explanation doesn't work when we call myFunc multiple times and change i between calls.  For instance i = 10; someFunc(); i = 20; someFunc().  The outputs are: 10 and 20.  Think the reason is Dart relies on lexical scoping as mention in my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying, `someFunc()` will print the last value you assigned to `i` before the call because `someFunc()` has access to `i`. Your answer is more technical than mine but I think we are talking about the same.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your explanation. I thought you implied that references were not used at all including to i.

Answer (score 0):

Dart uses lexical scoping as illustrated by the following.

```
void main() {
    int i = 10;
    var someFunc = () {
        int ni = i;  // gets the current value of i in main
        print(ni);
        i = 25;     // changes the value of i in main
    };
    i = 20;
    someFunc();    // prints 20
    print(i);      // prints 25 (since someFunc changed value)
    i = 30;   
    someFunc();    // prints 30
}
```

The different values printed for i is because Dart uses lexical scoping. A scope controls access and visibility to variables by other parts of the code.  In Dart, a new descendant scope is created with a curly bracket {.  The descendant scope has access to variables in the parent scope.

The function someFunc created a descendant scope which has access to variables in the parent scope (main).  Thus when i changes, someFunc gets access to this change.
(More examples: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2468332&seqNum=2)